# Dimension of eigenspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For an $ n \times n$ matrix $A$, eigenvalues are the roots of the polynomial $ p( \lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I_{n})$, the roots may be repetitive.

How do we conclude that the dimension of eigenspace corresponding to an eigenvalue is either (less than or equal to) or (equal to) the multiplicity of the root?